# This computer is not running genuine Windows issue

Tags: windows-7

Recently I had to restore and fix the MBR and the boot loader of my Genuine Windows 7 installation on a laptop. 
After that Boot Loader restoration, the Windows Activation Technologies dialog appears daily saying that my Windows 7 version is not genuine.

I had re-activated Windows 7 using my original serial key several times, using ether command line (slui.exe 3) or the GUI tool (Computer, Properties, Change Product Key). Every time I do that, Windows says that activation was succesful (Product activated successfully) but a few hour later, I have the same problem (the dialod appears and says that

From Control Panel I can see that My Windows IS activated!
Using slmgr /xpr I see that Windows is **permanently** activated!

So, either the Windows Activation Technologies is problematic (in which case I have a different problem because I cannot find the installation package!) or I need to somehow activate the Windows 7 despite the different opinion of slmgr!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it seems WAT is being problematic.

Try the following:

When turning on your computer, press F8 to access the advanced startup options. Choose "Repair Your Computer":

[image]

Load your user account and then the option to open a command prompt window:

[image]

Type `C:` to go to the root of your system partition. Then type the following lines (with a return after each line):

```
reg load HKLM\MY_SYSTEM "C:\Windows\System32\config\system"
reg delete HKLM\MY_SYSTEM\WPA /f
reg unload HKLM\MY_SYSTEM
```

Restart your system, open a command prompt as administrator and register your key with:

```
slmgr /ipk XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
```

After it, restart again and activate it.

Not really conventional, but it should be solved.

Comment: Hey look no hands. How about providing a source? Or did you do that from memory.

Comment: Sorry mate, no source on this one, just experience with WAT misbehaviour. Images were pulled from a quick google images search for the menu options.

Comment: "%~dp0Windows\ ???? Is that correct? Or should I write "\Windows\System32\..." instead?

Comment: Yes, it's correct, that's a variable to expand to the drive and path.

Comment: In that case, shouldn't it be something like: %~d0p0 (disk 0 partition 0) ??

Comment: No, that's neither disk nor partition, it's drive and path. It's exactly as shown. You can read more about the variable here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: It's not working. It says that "System was unable to find the specified registry key or value. BTW the system is Windows 64 (if that makes a difference).

Comment: @Peter Sorry, that was a huge lapse. The variable only works from within a batch file. I've edited that line in my answer, now it should work, assuming your system drive letter is `C:` (if not, just replace with the correct one). Good Luck.

Comment: I tried the solution and it seemed to work. For some hours. After half a day, the message reappeared again.

Comment: What can I do if I don't have the registry key? I got this laptop ages ago, and I'm having exactly the same problem. Is this fixable?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening Command prompt as admin(istrator) and type SLMGR -REARM Then restart your computer. It should be fixed!